# Old state still exist even after updating state in react

Tags: reactjs, rest, api, react-native, material-ui

React app containing Dynamic list
I need two operations

1.add

2.delete

Maintaining the list in this.state.tasks
and also in a db

In render

```
{this.state.tasks.map(tile => (
     <GridListTile cols='1'>           
     <Task content={tile} saveData={this.updateData}/>             
     </GridListTile>           
))}
```

There are 4 objects which are displayed as tiles
and now i am deleting the 1st object, i am updating in the db and fetching fresh list from db and assigning it to state

I am getting data from db

```
this.setState({tasks : data})
```

Since state is updated render function is called count of object is reducing to 3 but the deleted object still exist

Delete function :

```
deleteData(val) {
  var apiHeader = {
    'taskid': val
  }
  fetch("/api/deleteTask", {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: apiHeader
  })
  .then(res => this.getAvailableTasks()) 
}


getAvailableTasks() {
    fetch("/api/getTasks", {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
   },
    }).then(res => res.json())    // in response i am getting 3 only and also 3 documents are showing in db also
    .then(data => this.setState({tasks : data}));       
}
```

Comment: Could you please add the code for your case?
Also please try to log `this.state.tasks` inside `render`
Seems like they are not updated.

Comment: Added Required functions,In console this.state.tasks is showing correct only

Comment: @kaushik You're saying `console.log` shows the correct tasks, but `render` does not? Where are you logging? Are you binding your functions that call instance functions?

Comment: Yes, In render it is showing count as correct.If we delete 1st object it still exists but 2nd object is not visible.It is showing 1,3,4 even if we delete 1

Comment: @kaushik What's your `key` for each item? I don't see one in your snippet--have you tried not ignoring the ReactJS/ESLint `key` warnings?

Comment: It was array of objects containing taskid, status.. etc(Json array)

Comment: And also if i delete the last object it is displaying correct only,problem exist only if i delete starting objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by maintaining another initial state

```
this.baseState = this.state;
```

Before updating state object, assign the initial state and then update object

```
this.setState(this.baseState);
this.setState({tasks : data});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this solution or why it works, but I suspect it may have something to do with how `render()` is written -- but, that is not in the code with the original question.

Comment: While updating the state which is an array somehow old data is existing, so i tried to copy the initial state(this.basestate in constructor before add any objects to state). It worked

Comment: This does not work for me. not sure why this problem is happening. It is so weird. It is like this.setState does not work

Answer (score 1):

The way you declare functions will make them not recognize current context as `this`.
 You can try:

```
  deleteData =() => {
   // code
}
 getAvailableTasks = () => {
       // your code here
  }
```

Comment: I am using `this.getCompleteTask = this.getCompleteTask.bind(this);` in constructor. Hence i am able to access the function

Comment: Can you try putting `console.log` inside the last then handler for `this.state.tasks` and `data`?